# Add all data wthin range then check if it already exists

Tags: excel, range, addition, filedialog, vba

I'm using FileDialog to select other workbooks with this. I want to select multiple files at once.

Here is how I do it:

```
With fd

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb; *.xltx; *.xltm; *.xlt; *.xml; *.xlam; *.xla; *.xlw", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    If .Show = -1 Then

    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

            'Extract the Filename (without its file extension) to the File Path
            nPath = Mid(vrtSelectedItem, InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\") + 1)
            'nPath is Filename with path
            nFilename = Left(nPath, InStrRev(nPath, ".") - 1)

             If IsWorkBookOpen(vrtSelectedItem) = True Then
                    MsgBox "File already open."
             Else

                Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Open("" & vrtSelectedItem)
                Set wrkbk_destination = ThisWorkbook '<--- this where is will add the data from files selected with FD
                Set wrkbk_source = Workbooks("" & nFilename) '<--- this the selected files

         With wrkbk_destination.Sheets("Defect Log")
         .Activate

            ' I want to add the all values within range here but check if data already exist
            ' For example selected files have data within range of D11 : I11 , D12 : I12 and D13 : I13
            ' I want to add these but if data within D12 : I12 already exist It will skip adding data and continue with
            ' D13 : I13

                    End With
```

I just need an example of how to do it and I will be the one to point where this added data will be display in wrkbk_destination.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points

1. You can do away with one of the object `wrkbk` or `wrkbk_source`
2. You don't need to check if the data already exists. Simply copy the data across as there is just a small range `D11:I13` to be copied across. In the end use `.RemoveDuplicates`. It will be much faster.
3. You do not need to keep on activating your workbook/worksheet. You can directly perform the operation. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '

    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wrkbk_destination = ThisWorkbook

    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb; *.xltx;" & _
        "*.xltm; *.xlt; *.xml; *.xlam; *.xla; *.xlw", 1

        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        If .Show = -1 Then

        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
             If IsWorkBookOpen(vrtSelectedItem) = True Then
                MsgBox "File already open."
             Else
                Set wrkbk_source = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)

                With wrkbk_destination.Sheets("Defect Log")
                    lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    .Range("D" & lRow & ":I" & (lRow + 2)).Value = _
                    wrkbk_source.Sheets(1).Range("D11:I13").Value
                End With

                wrkbk_source.Close (False)
            End If
        Next vrtSelectedItem
    End With

    With wrkbk_destination.Sheets("Defect Log")
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Change xlNo to xlYes if the column has headers
        .Columns("D1:I" & lRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:= _
        Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick response, and thank you for introducing to me the function .RemoveDuplicate heh! There is always an easy way in programming. I haven't tried this yet but I have one question, will this add all value in every row if all values are unique? example in row 12 .Range D12 to I12, Row 13 .Range (D13 to I13) and Row 14 .Range (D14 to I14) all values per Row set are unique so this will all be added.

Comment: Yup :) Unique or Duplicate... they will be added and then `.RemoveDuplicate` will remove all duplicates (keeping one entry)